# No instance of function template matches the argument list error

Tags: c++

I am not sure why I am getting this error of argument list mismatch. The function template instantiation seems to match the one in main...
Can you tell me what's wrong please?
Here is my code:

```
    //using decltype operator

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<class T1, class T2> 
auto product( T1 v1[], T2 v2[], size_t count ) ->decltype( v1[0] * v2[0] ) {
    decltype( v1[0] * v2[0] ) sum( 0 );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ ) sum += v1[i] * v2[i];
    return sum;
}

int main ( void ) {
    double x[] =   { 100.5, 99.5, 88.7, 77.8 };
    short  y[] =   { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    long   z[] =   { 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L };
    size_t n = 4;
    cout << "Result type is "<< typeid( product ( x, y, n ) ).name() << endl;
    cout << "Result  is " << product ( x, y, n ) << endl;
    cout << "Result type is " << typeid( product ( z, y, n ) ).name() << endl;
    cout << "Result is " << product ( z, y, n ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiles fine with GCC 4.5.1.

Comment: Compiles fine here: http://ideone.com/KTncj. What compiler you are using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Pro 2010

Comment: @GKED: don't except visual studio to work well with c++11

Comment: It works fine for me too. - gcc 4.6.1

Comment: @GKED if you're looking at the IntelliSence errors, its has some issues, but it should compile fine.

Comment: Well, I am got this code from a book "Visual C++ 2010" :)

Comment: @MerickOWA, yes you are right, it does do the work, Something is wrong with intellisence :).

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I figured from the comments of others that there was a problem with IntelliScence. The code is right.